# Is there a way to insert BINARY data directly as binary literals with SQL?

Tags: sql, h2

I have a data dump of binary strings which I need to insert on a H2 table. While I can easily create a table with a datatype `BINARY(<size>)`, so far I have not been successful in inserting the data directly as binary literals

eg.

```sql
INSERT INTO <table> VALUES(1111); -- This would insert the decimal value
INSERT INTO <table> VALUES(X'F'); -- This is okay but then I have to preprocess the data and convert them to hex
```

Is there a way that the same can be easily achieved in H2 may be even using some functions on the binary literals?

Java on which H2 is build allows binary literals like `0b1111` so there may be a chance that the same functionality is exposed someway that I am not aware of.

Comment: The allowed flavors of value are documented [here](https://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#value). The only binary literal format is [`X'...'`](https://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#bytes). The fact that h2 is written in Java is not particularly relevant; SQL is a separate language. There ought to be no reason for you to process strings, though; just use parameterized commands and use `byte[]` values directly.